# Copy values via MySQL query (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've Wordpress + Woocommerce website. I need to export .xml for other website.

In post_meta table there are fields:
_sku
woocommerce_xml_disabled
woocommerce_xml_EAN

I need to build this query:

```
if '_sku' not empty
copy value from '_sku' to 'woocommerce_xml_EAN'
if '_sku' is empty
set 'woocommerce_xml_disabled' value to '1'.
```

Client used SKU field to put EAN codes and some product have same EANs. This field does not accept duplicates so there are cases where values looks like this '9001616391101 (1)', '9001616391101 (2)'. It would be great if query could remove those (1) numbers after copying. 'woocommerce_xml_EAN' can have duplicate EANs.

This would save me a lot of work.

Here's small sample of SQL:

```
(181195, 14947, 'cmsms_breadcrumbs', 'default'),  
(181196, 14947, 'cmsms_custom_breadcrumbs', 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";}}'),  
(181198, 14947, 'woocommerce_xml_disabled', ''),  
(181199, 14947, 'woocommerce_xml_alternative_name', ''),  
(181200, 14947, 'woocommerce_xml_alternative_desc', ''),  
(181201, 14947, 'woocommerce_xml_group', ''),  
(181202, 14947, '_woocommerce_gpf_data', 'a:0:{}'),  
(181217, 14946, '_thumbnail_id', '9874'),  
(181218, 14946, 'total_sales', '0'),
```

#### Single product sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_postmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=185004 ;

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
(173877, 14819, '_visibility', 'visible'),
(173878, 14819, '_stock_status', 'instock'),
(173879, 14819, '_downloadable', 'no'),
(173880, 14819, '_virtual', 'no'),
(173881, 14819, '_regular_price', '13.9'),
(173882, 14819, '_sale_price', ''),
(173883, 14819, '_purchase_note', ''),
(173884, 14819, '_featured', 'no'),
(173889, 14819, '_sku', '9001616391101 (5)'),
(173893, 14819, '_price', '13.9'),
(173919, 14819, 'woocommerce_xml_disabled', '1'),
(173923, 14819, '_woocommerce_gpf_data', 'a:0:{}'),
(173938, 14819, '_thumbnail_id', '10851'),
(173939, 14819, 'total_sales', '0'),
(182118, 14819, 'woocommerce_xml_EAN', '9001616391101')
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample of what the original table values look like, which will be helpful for those of us who don't know the inherent structure of a WP `post_meta` table? When posting a SQL question, it is a good idea to show a sample rowset from all related tables, together with a sample of what the query output should produce using that same input sample.

Comment: Here's table description.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta
I' ll try to post some samples.

Comment: I've added SQL sample to original question.

Comment: The posted sample rows don't contain any involving the fields you want to modify. Please update it to include values for `_sku` and `woocommerce_xml_EAN` and the post's related `woocommerce_xml_disabled`. Also be sure to include some which have the `(1)` that you would like stripped off. This all helps us to setup test queries locally or at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Here's sample meta data of single product: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf433 I hope this will help

Comment: Is every post certain to have a row in wp_postmeta for `_sku`, whether empty or nonempty, or do some posts not have an associated wp_postmeta `_sku` field? If some lack one, would that be treated the same way as a blank `_sku`,  setting `woocommerce_xml_disabled = 1`?

Comment: Not all posts are products. Every product post has a row for _sku even if empty. In my case if _sku is empty it means that there's no EAN for this product and I want to exclude it from xml by setting `woocommerce_xml_disabled` to 1. If product never had an EAN before there is no `woocommerce_xml_EAN` record. It shoud be added by creating new `meta_id`.

Comment: I never saw any reply on this last week. Did this answer meet your needs?

Answer (score 2):

You have complex requirements here, made more difficult by the key/value structure of the `wp_postmeta` table.  Let's tackle it in two steps. The first will be to update rows where the `woocommerce_xml_EAN` field already exists to the corresponding `_sku` value, and simultaneously strip off the parenthetical `(1)` values [using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).  In this step, the `woocommerce_xml_disabled` also gets set to `1` if the `_sku` is empty.

This will all be accomplished by joining `wp_postmeta` to itself. On one side of the join, the `_sku` is used and on the other, it is matched by `post_id` to update the `woocommerce_xml_EAN, woocommerce_xml_disabled` fields.

```
UPDATE
  wp_postmeta sku
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ean 
    ON sku.post_id = ean.post_id
    -- Join conditions ensure only the needed keys are modified
    AND sku.meta_key = '_sku'
    AND ean.meta_key IN ('woocommerce_xml_EAN', 'woocommerce_xml_disabled')
 SET ean.meta_value = CASE
   -- the key/value store is crazy here :-)
   -- First strip the (1) from the _sku and set the 
   -- resultant value into meta_value for the woocommerce_xml_EAN key
   WHEN ean.meta_key = 'woocommerce_xml_EAN'
     THEN TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sku.meta_value, '(', 1)) 
   -- Then set '1' for the disabled field if _sku is empty
   WHEN ean.meta_key = 'woocommerce_xml_disabled' AND sku.meta_value = ''
     THEN '1'
   -- But make sure to use the original value if sku wasn't empty!
   WHEN ean.meta_key = 'woocommerce_xml_disabled' AND sku.meta_value <> ''
     THEN ean.meta_value
   END
 WHERE sku.meta_key = '_sku'
   AND ean.meta_key IN ('woocommerce_xml_EAN', 'woocommerce_xml_disabled');
```

Now the second stage, since some `_sku` may not have an associated `woocommerce_xml_EAN`, that needs to be added with an `INSERT`. We'll use an `INSERT INTO... SELECT` using a null `LEFT JOIN` to find those which do not already exist, and insert them. It uses the same `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` trick.

```
 INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
   SELECT
     -- Insert a new row with the post_id,
     sku.post_id,
     -- literal string for the EAN
     'woocommerce_xml_EAN',
     -- And the modified _sku value
     TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sku.meta_value, '(', 1))
   FROM
     wp_postmeta sku
     LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ean
     ON sku.post_id = ean.post_id
      AND sku.meta_key = '_sku'
      AND ean.meta_key = 'woocommerce_xml_EAN'
    WHERE
      sku.meta_key = '_sku'
      -- NULL on the ean side of the join means it doesn't exist already
      AND ean.meta_id IS NULL;
```

And here is a demonstration to prove this all actually works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30b84/2

In the demo, I added two additional `post_id` which had no previous value for the EAN to verify that the `woocommerce_xml_EAN` is created for them. Their `post_id` are `14820, 14821`, and you'll find them at the bottom of the result set.

Comment: On posts like this my eyes are shining. That's a moment where you feel like you found a diamond on SO!